# Is it a good thing to Raise Exceptions intentionally in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am developing a PL function in Postgres, and in it I am modifying records of a table, according to some logic, then I execute a final query (basically counting), and if the number I get is positive, I throw an exception to rollback the transaction (since PostgreSQL's function doesn't support transactions explicitly).

So is this a good method to emulate transactions? Do you have better suggestions ?

PS: I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 but I am migrating to 9.3 soon, if this may help somehow.

Comment: That has nothing to do with "emulation transactions". It's simple error handling and it is the proper way to do it - otherwise how should the caller know that something went wrong. I would probably even do that in a DBMS that allows you to commit inside a stored procedure. Btw: your statement "*doesn't support transactions explicitly*" is a bit imprecise. Statements inside a function are fully transactional: they are part of the transaction of the caller but are not allowed to `commit` or `rollback` that transaction on their own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to abort a transaction within a function, then yes, raising an exception is a good choice.

You can use subtransactions within PL/PgSQL functions by using `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` blocks within the function. Use an inner `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block and within it `RAISE` an exception with a user defined SQLSTATE. Catch the exception in the `EXCEPTION` block.

A `RAISE` (of `ERROR` or higher) within a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block will roll back work done within that block, as if you had used a `SAVEPOINT` and `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`.

Functions cannot force a rollback of the top level transaction; if you `RAISE` an exception, an outer pl/pgsql function can catch the exception in a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block, or the client can use a `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`.

Comment: Thanks, this is far better than making the whole function throw an exception! However, just for clarification, *any* Raise level will cause the begin exception block to rollback work done or only EXCEPTIONs ??

Comment: @FearUs `ERROR` or greater.

Answer (score 4):

I have used this solution in the past.  At issue is that the PLPGSQL language does not support the use of SAVEPOINT and ROLLBACK.  Transactions *wrap* functions, not the other way around.

RAISE is the proper methodology to notify the client of some internal condition within a function.  There are several levels of RAISE, the "worst" is EXCEPTION which will abort/rollback your transactions UNLESS something catches the exception and suppresses it.

For testing, use

```
`RAISE DEBUG 'some comment %', var;`
```

If you want to put something in your logs, but don't want to rollback, you can (typically) raise a WARNING.  (Any level of RAISE can go to your logs, it depends on your configuration)